# Is there a way to use HTML "pattern" with ng-click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

The HTML pattern will be ignored if I press the button. Is there a way in AngularJS to evaluate the pattern beforehand?

```
<form>
  <input tpye="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" pattern="[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])" ng-model="day" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" ng-click="doSomething(day)" />
</form>
```

Comment: In your method `doSomething(day)`, you could check [if your form is valid](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) with `<formName>.$valid`.

Comment: Add a ``name`` attribute to your form. For example ``<form name="myForm"...``. Then you can use ``ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"`` on the ``submit`` element to disable the submit button until the form validates. And true, the link posted above by @MaximeMorin is a must-read.